# Launching programs as another user on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, runas, usersession

In a Mac OS X with more than one  users , is there any API or piece of code that Run a process as another user in Objective C?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges**, take a look e.g. at http://www.michaelvobrien.com/blog/2009/07/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-a-simple-example/

```
// Create authorization reference
AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;
OSStatus status;
status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,
                             kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorizationRef);

// Run the tool using the authorization reference
char *tool = "/sbin/dmesg";
char *args[] = {NULL};
FILE *pipe = NULL;
status = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef, tool,
                                            kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, args, &pipe);
```